# Flex: Properties of an item are not accessible in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

**This question talks about verticalAlign property but the answer might be relevant for other style properties as well.**

I have a grid object in my mxml file:

```
<mx:Grid width = "100%"
         height = "100%"
         id = "myGrid">
    <mx:GridRow width = "100%">
        <mx:GridItem verticalAlign = "middle">
          // Some design code
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

I'm trying to add rows programmatically using action script:

```
var configurationItem:GridItem = new GridItem();
```

But there is no `verticalAlign` property for the grid item instance. Is there a way to set this property in action script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verticalAlign is a style and not a property.

To achive that from ActionScript use:

```
var configurationItem:GridItem = new GridItem();
configurationItem.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hope that helps. And as you say this applies for any style property in flex controls.